# EntityType has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have a simple WCF service project to which I've added Entity Framework. As you can see the Entity class looks well. However when I'm running the project,  I'm getting weird exception `EntityType 'AccountOperationEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.` I've never had problems like this before with EF. Could someone explain me what 's going on? I get this exception with all classes I create.

```
public class AccountOperationEntity
{
    [Key]
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountEntity Account { get; set; }
    public OperationType OperationType { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

This also happens when I try to `enable-migrations`.

Comment: @KasunjithBimal shouldn't it work without [Table]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uint is just not supported as key in Entity Framework.

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1489

Comment: Thanks, it was really cryptic to me. The error should say something like "uint not supported".